# Poner id(obtenida de mysql) en data-text de un codigo de barras

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, html5

Lo estoy haciendo con jsbarcode y en data-text, en vez de 23 tendría que poner el **id** obtenida de la base de datos

```
<img data-value="12345" data-text="23-000001" class="codigo"/>
```

Despues al darle al boton, tiene que guardarme el **data-text**, del codigo de barras en **mysql**

```
<button id="guardar" type="button" onClick="myFunction();">Generar Datos</button>
```

En la función tengo la ejecución de JsBarcode y estoy usando Laravel. 
He puesto esto en la funcion create

```
public function create(Expediente $id)
    {
        
        return view('expediente.crear');
    }
```

Pero me da un error que no se encuentra la id, soy nueva en esto.

Comment: https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode

Comment: eso me sale, lo que necesito es que se me rellene la letra de codigo con **id** obtenida de la base de datos que ya estara creada, y despues 6 digitos que vayan de manera consecutiva

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, no pones que quieres realmente, si te sale errores, no te funciona usando x cosas, etc

Comment: ya la he editado

Answer (score 0):

Esto sería la parte de javascript con la librería...

Para el tema de grabarlo en BD con laravel entiendo que deberías enviar desde myFunction una petición ajax con el código de barras para almacenarlo.

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  //Utilizar la librería..
  JsBarcode('.codigo').init();
  
  //Obtención de valores para el tratamiento si es necesario...
  let codigos = document.querySelectorAll('.codigo');
  for ( let code of codigos ) {
    console.log(code.dataset.value)
    console.log(code.dataset.text)
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsbarcode/3.11.4/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>

Lo estoy haciendo con jsbarcode, pero el código lo pongo yo manual

<img data-value="12345" data-text="23-000001" class="codigo"/>

Pero cuando le de a un boton tiene que generarme el código de barras con ese formato y almacenarlo en la base de datos

<button id="guardar" type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Generar Datos</button>
```

Comment: Eso si que me ha salido pero lo de coger la **id** del codigo(obtenida de la base de datos) para ponerlo en la propiedad **data-text** y que se formen despues 6 digitos de manera consecutiva no se como hacerlo. No he dado ajax.

Comment: Entonces deberás mirar que en una aplicación de laravel tienes un fichero app.js con AXIOS que permite hacer peticiones asynchronous de tal manera... que tienes que tener una Route::post('/damecodigos',[ControladorCodigosCustomLaravel::class,'damecodigos']) y en el método de la clase llamar a la base de datos para que los obtenga

Comment: ```public function create(Expediente $id){return view('expediente.crear');}``` Esto no me funciona

Comment: Laravel sí tiene algo bueno es que los errores te los explica bastante bien...

Comment: Muchas gracias.